# "Is not you?" or "Are not you?"?

Tags: questions

What statement is correct between these two?

> Because each of us is a qualified programmer (are not you?)...

or

> Because each of us is a qualified programmer (is not you?)...

That the context would be more clear here is a more complete statement

> Because each of us is a qualified programmer (are not you?) and in
>   contrast to the student each of us knows that there already exists
>   standard algorithm ....

Comment: Neither of them; it should be *"aren't you?"* (current English) or maybe *"are you not?"* (19th century English).

Comment: @Peter Shor And what is the difference between "are not you" and "aren't you"?

Comment: Here, I'd use '(assuming this includes you)'.

Comment: *"aren't you?"* is the contracted form of *"are you not?"*; *"are not you?"* is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Peter Shor I want to write this phrase in an article. So what is the better: to use the contracted form or non-contracted form in an article?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth It is an idea. I will think about it.

Comment: You could use either one. Because you're talking directly to the reader, the article is clearly not extremely formal, so I think the contracted form would fit the tone better.

Comment: Amongst Lancashire [though not Merseyside] speakers, I hear the '19th century' form being used quite unselfconsciously: "I'm not going to the party" - "*Are* you not?" [expressing surprise].

Answer (score 2):

With *you* we use *are*, not *is* (*I am, you are, he/she/it/one is, we are, you are, they are*).

The statement claiming you are not would be "You are not" and to make it a question we invert the subject and verb to produce "Are you not?"

We can also have "Aren't you?" Starting from the statement "You aren't" we can invert in the same manner to produce "Aren't you?". While this expands to "Are not you?" we generally treat *aren't* as a single word, regardless of the fact that it is a contraction of two.

"Are not you?" would not be a standard form.

(It *might* be used as the start of a longer rhetorical question, but this would be a matter of deliberately using a very old-fashioned phrasing for emphasis, not a normal wording, and running a risk of sounding pretentious or silly even when used deliberately.)